# Radio button checked is not working for row 7?(I have rouond about 30 rows) IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html4

[image]

we are dynamically creating the radio buttons in for loop(JSTL). But when row 7 is encountered, the radio button is not getting selected.

```html
<td width="35" id="1049"><table width="100%" id="1050">

<tr id="1052">
<td class=label width="40%"  id="1053">SAMPLE ABC</td>
<td width="20%"  id="1054"><input class=columnReadRow type=radio value=62|21|V name=columnRadio__7_0 id="1055"> </td>
<td width="20%"  id="1056"><INPUT class=columnWriteRow type=radio value=62|21|E name=columnRadio__7_0 id="1057"> </td>
<td width="20%"  id="1058"><INPUT class=columnNARow CHECKED type=radio value=62|21 name=columnRadio__7_0 id="1059"> </td></tr>
<tr id="1060">
<td class=label width="40%"  id="1061">SAMPLE CDE</td>
<td width="20%"  id="1062"><INPUT class=columnReadRow type=radio value=62|22|V name=columnRadio__7_1 id="1063"> </td>
<td width="20%"  id="1064"><INPUT class=columnWriteRow type=radio value=62|22|E name=columnRadio__7_1 id="1065"> </td>
<td width="20%"  id="1066"><INPUT class=columnNARow CHECKED type=radio value=62|22 name=columnRadio__7_1 id="1067"> </td></tr></table></td>
```

Comment: Hi there, please share full code and phrase a real question. Thanks!

Comment: Checked="checked" Not Rendering As Checked Radio Button In IE.. I can't share my code but i will try to post the sample code

Comment: As you mentioned, i have shared the code. The above code is for the 7th row in a table where we are having two radio button groups columnRadio__7_1 and columnRadio__7_0. checked is present in one of the radio button, but IE is not making it as selected.

Comment: just to make sure, you should always write `attribute="value"` (note the `"`).

Comment: Hi Felix, i have used attribute="value" since it is generated source of html in IE, i have pasted it directly

Comment: And other browsers render the page correctly?

Comment: Sample code is not enough in this case, it works fine in IE, too...

Comment: Probably the `!doctype` is wrong, use `<!doctype html>`, use lowercase tag and attribute names and put quotes around attribute values. As `<input type="radio" checked="checked" name="some_name" id="unique_id" />`.